# What is a sheet of multiple photos called?

Tags: film, terminology

I've come across a sheet of multiple individual photos, I'm guessing they are something to do with a video editing as they are of Bob Marley at a kids birthday party which I remember having happened. Can anyone tell me what the sheet of photos are called as I would really like to research them but I just come across a blank.

Comment: Try searching for [extract video frames](https://www.startpage.com/do/search?q=extract%20video%20frames) or [extract video images](https://www.startpage.com/do/search?q=extract%20video%20images) or [extract video thumbnails](https://www.startpage.com/do/search?q=extract%20video%20thumbnails) or ... and you'll probably get plenty of suggestions; e.g. top of my search [Extract video frames to images using vlc media player, at raymond.cc](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/extract-video-frames-to-images-using-vlc-media-player/)

Answer (score 10):

It sounds to me that what you are describing is what we call a **contact sheet** or a **proof sheet**. It's called that because in the film days, it was made by physically placing the negatives on the print paper (in contact with it, that is) rather than projecting through an enlarger. These contact sheets were used to select which pictures on a roll of film merited further work, without wasting time and materials.

The example you have *might* be from a video, but it might also be from a series of pictures taken in quick sequence, perhaps using a motor drive. Searching for "bob marley contact sheet" turns up a number of examples from photographers Allan Ballard, David Burnett, Richard Aaron, and others. For example:

[image]

While we don't make them this way in the digital realm, the terminology lives on — you'll find "contact sheet" options in Lightroom and other software.

Comment: Trivia: I used to get contact sheets for my B&W shoots, and one day decided to order a contact sheet for a color roll.  Since it wasn't a "standard" item,  I paid more for the color contact sheet than I would have for a full set of 3x5 prints.